# Saving Crypto++ objects to std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector, crypto++

I want to save Crypto++ keys to `std::vector<uint8_t>`. Unfortunately there is only `CryptoPP::StringSink`, that takes `std::string` reference but no `CryptoPP::VectorSink` that would take a reference to `std::vector`.

**Following code works fine**

```
std::string spki;
CryptoPP::StringSink ss(spki);

CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey publicKey(...);
publicKey.Save(ss);
```

**But I want this**

```
std::vector<uint8_t> spki;
CryptoPP::VectorSink vs(spki);

CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey publicKey(...);
publicKey.Save(vs);
```

**The problem**

`VectorSink` can not be created just by using a typedef because of  `traits_type::char_type` inside `StringSinkTemplate`:

```
using CryptoPP::StringSinkTemplate;
typedef StringSinkTemplate< std::vector<byte> > VectorSink;

In file included from cryptopp-test.cpp:65:
In file included from /usr/local/include/cryptopp/files.h:5:
/usr/local/include/cryptopp/filters.h:590:22: error: no member named
      'traits_type' in 'std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char>
      >'
        typedef typename T::traits_type::char_type char_type;
                         ~~~^
cryptopp-test.cpp:243:20: note: in instantiation of template class
      'CryptoPP::StringSinkTemplate<std::vector<unsigned char,
      std::allocator<unsigned char> > >' requested here
        VectorSink vs(spki);
```

How can I create a `VectorSink`?

Comment: You might want to explain *why* you want to use a vector instead of a string? Otherwise this question is just an example of [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: That's nice and clean. You might consider adding it to the [Patch Page](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Category:Patch) on the Crypto++ wiki. To qualify for the page, you have to assign copyright to the Crypto++ project. Here's an example of what it might look like: [Written and placed in Public Domain by Roman. Copyright assigned to Crypto++ Project](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/blake2.cpp).

Comment: If you don't want to assign copyright, then that's fine. The project asks for the copyright to (1) ensure users get a single licensing term (Public Domain or Boost), and (2) Wei Dai has the requisite control to comply with export regulations. Wei copyrights the library as a whole due to export regulations and controls.

Comment: I would rather prefer `StringSinkTemplate` to be renamed / fixed, because the implementation is almost identical. But I assigned the copyright just in case someone wants to use it freely.

Comment: *"I would rather prefer `StringSinkTemplate` to be renamed / fixed..."* - Bug reports and pull requests are made at [Crypto++ Issues](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues). Its not clear to me what is not working with `StringSinkTemplate`, so be sure to clearly state it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Working implementation of VectorSink**

```
// Written and placed in the public domain by rrmmnn
// Copyright assigned to the Crypto++ project.

namespace CryptoPP {

class VectorSink : public Bufferless<Sink> {
public:

  VectorSink(std::vector<uint8_t>& out)
    : _out(&out) {
  }

  size_t Put2(const byte *inString, size_t length, int /*messageEnd*/, bool /*blocking*/) {
    _out->insert(_out->end(), inString, inString + length);
    return 0;
  }

private:  
  std::vector<uint8_t>* _out;
};

}
```