# Custom source for Crypto++

Tags: c++, crypto++

I have made my own custom stream classes for binary I/O. Now I'm trying to make them compatible with Crypto++ library. I have found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39350337/saving-crypto-objects-to-stdvector) that deals with custom sink and implemented my own. Now I need to implement a source. I've searched through the documentation and there seems to be a huge inheritance hierarchy so I can't understand it yet.

Can someone provide an example code?

Here's the part of my stream class:

```
/// \brief Base class for a binary input stream.
/// \details Binary streams are used for low level unformatted I/O. Built on top
/// of standard streams, this system takes care of endianness and provides
/// convenient << and >> overloads. This class is designed to mirror
/// std::istream.

class BinaryInputStream : public virtual BinaryStreamBase
{
public:
    /// \brief Returns whether last I/O operation has completed successfully.
    /// \return True if last I/O operation has completed successfully,
    /// false otherwise.
    virtual bool IsGood() const = 0;

    /// \brief Returns whether end-of-file has been reached.
    /// \return True if end-of-file has been reached, false otherwise.
    virtual bool IsEOF() const = 0;

    /// \brief Returns whether recoverable error has occured.
    /// \return True if recoverable error has occured, false otherwise.
    virtual bool IsFail() const = 0;

    /// \brief Returns whether non-recoverable error has occured.
    /// \return True if non-recoverable error has occured, false otherwise.
    virtual bool IsBad() const = 0;

    /// \brief Reads a sequence of bytes from the stream.
    /// \param[in,out] buffer Buffer to write to.
    /// \param[in] size Number of bytes to read.
    /// \return Reference to this stream.
    /// \warning You are responsible for allocating the buffer and ensuring that
    /// it contains enough space to hold the data. If number of bytes to read is
    /// greater than the size of the buffer, the behavior is undefined.
    virtual BinaryInputStream& Read(char* buffer, std::size_t size) = 0;
};
```

Comment: This is really nice of you to share this interesting story. Thank you. @edit: was there any question you wanted to ask?

Comment: Oops, sorry, added question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to look at the source code of crypto++ and copy most of the implementation from [`FileSource`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_file_source.html) class. The relevant files are [`files.h`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/files_8h_source.html) and [`files.cpp`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/files_8cpp_source.html).

First, we need to look at the [`FileSource`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_file_source.html) class. It inherits from `SourceTemplate<FileStore>`. So we need to examine [`FileStore`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_file_store.html) class. It inherits from `Store`, `FilterPutSpaceHelper` and `NotCopyable`. We need to create class which also inherits from these classes.

Our store class must have a default constructor and implement the following virtual functions: `TransferTo2`, `CopyRangeTo2` and `StoreInitialize`. `StoreInitialize` can be private.

Finally, our source class needs only constructors and if you look at [`files.h`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/files_8h_source.html), [`FileSource`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_file_source.html) is implemented entirely in a header file.

The full implementation code is confined to [`files.h`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/files_8h_source.html) and [`files.cpp`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/files_8cpp_source.html) so there's no need to copy it in this answer.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand why your `BinaryInputStream` is useful as a `Source`. Its not clear to me what benefit it offers. For example, a library source offers `SourceExhausted()`, so there's no need for an `IsEOF()`.

Comment: I use it to do binary I/O. For example reading data from files or sockets.